# Missing /etc/init.d/ipsec script after installing strongswan 5.3.2 from source

Tags: ipsec, ubuntu-14.04, init.d, init, strongswan

Ubuntu 14.04 (Amazon's Ubuntu AMI).  Installed strongswan 5.3.2 from source (latest version in repo is too old and doesn't work).  1 question:

1) Noticed that the /init.d/ipsec (or /init/) script is missing.  I'm a linux newb, so I assume this is the case because I installed from source and I'm expected to build this script myself somehow?  Because the script is missing, I can't configure the OS to auto start the ipsec service upon boot.  My question is **How do I get the ipsec init script?**

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like strongswan only ships systemd units, not old-style init or upstart scripts. Consider using a distribution other than Ubuntu or Debian.

Comment: Strange.  Version 5.1.2 shipped with ipsec init.